# Clickable Nodes Networkx Python

Tags: python, nodes, networkx, clickable

I am wondering how I can make clickable nodes in NetworkX in Python.
E.g. I click on a node and it calls a function.

Been doing research but wasn't able to find a solid solution. Here's some example code:

```
import networkx as nx
from pylab import rcParams, matplotlib
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def nodeNetworkGraph(nodes_found):
    rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 8,4
    sb.set_style('whitegrid')
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    label_dict = {}

    if nodes_found == 0:
        G = nx.gn_graph(1)
        label_dict.update({0: "No Nodes"})
    else:
        for i in range(nodes_found):
            if i+1 == nodes_found & nodes_found != 1:
                label_dict.update({i: i+1})
                break
            elif nodes_found == 1:
                G = nx.gn_graph(nodes_found)
                label_dict.update({i: i+1})
            else:
                label_dict.update({i: i+1})
                G.add_edge(i,i+1)
    G = G.to_undirected()
    G.remove_edges_from(G.edges())
    nx.draw_circular(G, labels=label_dict, node_color='yellow', with_labels=True)

    plt.show()

nodeNetworkGraph(40)
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you :)

Comment: The function 'draw_circular' calls 'draw_networkx_nodes' to draw the nodes, which itself is basically a wrapper around matplotlib's `scatter`. [Here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/event_handling.html) is the matplotlib tutorial for pick event handling, and [here](https://medium.com/@gorjanz/data-analysis-in-python-interactive-scatterplot-with-matplotlib-6bb8ad2f1f18) is another tutorial using `scatter` specifically.

Comment: Also, you can look at a fork of the networkx drawing utilities (which I created some time ago) that allows dragging of nodes so there is a lot of pick event handling in this specific context [there.](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph/blob/master/netgraph/_main.py#L1767).

Comment: @PaulBrodersen thank you for the response! I've been trying to wrap my head around event handling with networkx graphs from the links you've sent but to no result. Do you know how to create event connections for networkx graphs?

Comment: @PaulBrodersen thank you for the help, all working now! :)